# Can I safely keep the results of FirebaseApp # getInstance() and FirebaseAuth # getInstance() in static fields for the lifetime of my app?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've read the [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#getInstance()) and they *appear* to indicate that it should be safe but I wanted to ask the community.

I'm asking because I'd like to either keep those instances in static fields somewhere, or keep using `getInstance()` as-needed throughout my app. Probably the former.

Comment: I'd change the question around a bit. If you ask "can I safely keep a `FirebaseApp`instance around?", the answer is "yes".

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. But would the same `FirebaseApp` instance always imply I'd get the same `FirebaseAuth` instance as well? I wanted to be explicit. I can change this to be about both APIs.

Comment: looks like the answer is "yes" also for the entire family of FirebaseXXX.getInstance() methods, per https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp . @FrankvanPuffelen if you write your comment as an answer (pointing out it's true for all FirebaseXXX...) i will mark it as accepted, thx